# warning: Wlogical-not-parentheses

Tags: c++, g++, warnings

I am confronted with a problem of a few days.

I receive this warning when compiling my program.

```
In member function 'void CClientManager::RESULT_SAFEBOX_LOAD(CPeer*, SQLMsg*)':
661:25: warning: logical not is only applied to the left hand side of comparison [-Wlogical-not-parentheses]
        if (!dwSkillVnum > 120)
                         ^
```

And another warning :

```
661:25: warning: comparison of constant '120' with boolean expression is always false [-Wbool-compare]
```

I want to mention that these two warnings occurred after I moved on g ++ 5.1.0
Before I used g ++ 4.2 and I had this warning.
 So how can I fix this.

Here is my file :  http://pastebin.com/fWYYmXsH

Comment: You probably want to write `if (!(dwSkillVnum > 120))`, to fix this. Otherwise `!` is applied to `dwSkillVnum`.

Comment: wow, now it Works. :(   But why on g++4.2 i not have that warning?

Comment: g++5.1.0 was improved to give you better warning messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `operator!()` has higher precedence than `operator>()`, so effectively you turn `!dwSkillVnum` to a `bool`and compare that with an integer value.

To fix this put parenthesis properly as mentioned in the warning:

```
 if (!(dwSkillVnum > 120))
   // ^                 ^
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!dwSkillVnum > 120)
```

is the same as

```
if ((!dwSkillVnum) > 120)
```

which will never be executed since the promoted bool `(!dwSkillVnum)` will be zero or one, thus not greater than `120`. You most likely mean

```
if (!(dwSkillVnum > 120))
```

or

```
if (dwSkillVnum <= 120)
```

instead.